# does it mutating the data with directly replacing list

Tags: javascript, mutators

Does the following code, mutate the `history`? If it does how to avoid it.

```
const index = findIndex(propEq('editorId', editorId))(editorWrappers);

if (index !== -1) {
    const editorHistory = editorWrappers[index].history || [];
    const history = filter(item => item.resource !== resource || (item.resource === resource && item.name !== name), editorHistory);
    console.log('history', history);
    editorWrappers[index].history = history;
}

return [...editorWrappers];
};
```

Comment: It reassigns the property here `editorWrappers[index].history = history;` Just remove that line and it won't be reassigned

Comment: Which `history` you ask about ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I was overwriting the `history` so I can update the object.  Was it doing mutating the parent object?

Comment: Yes, assigning to `editorWrappers[index].history = history;` will change the `editorWrappers[index]` object - that's what assignment does

Comment: So how to avoid it but still update the `history` to the parent object?